# trouble connecting to LocalDB in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I'm going through the Contoso University tutorial found [here](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) on asp.net and can't get past the first part due to connectionString problems.

I'm getting this error message after i enter the connection string and try to view the database.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a       connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime
>   error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows
>   Application event log for error details.

I was looking at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gaurav/archive/2013/12/21/deployment-of-sql-express-localdb-on-iis.aspx) msdn blog which mentions the same error under the "Deploying LocalDB on IIS Server " section but i honestly have no idea what it wants me to do.

How can do i fix this error? Is it a problem with the tutorial or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: go to web.config and see what's inside <connectionstrings> post back the snippet code

Comment: it's what i copied from the tutorial...<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity1;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>

Comment: you should have your own connection string . did you change lacalDB with your localdb name?

Comment: no, i only followed the tutorial which has you copy that code into the web.config

Comment: try the connection string i just posted

Comment: the code you posted gave me this error message..."A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Comment: @user7868 Can you even connect to `(LocalDb)\v11.0`, either in Visual Studio data explorer, SQL Server Management Studio, or even SQLCMD.exe? Your connection string looks correct as far as that tutorial goes. Regardless, you still need to check the Windows Application" event log first as it should reduce a lot of the guess-work here.

Comment: @srutzky i tried connected through management studio and got the same error as above (error 50). i'm not sure how to use the event log but i'll look into it

Comment: @user7868 Go to Control Panel / Administrative Tools to look at Event Viewer. You might have the instance under another name such that it is not `v11.0` but instead just `V12` or `Projects` or something else.

Comment: @srutzky I've been looking through the event viewer and i can't find anything related to what i'm looking for.

Comment: @srutzky So after i get the error message, i recieve two "events" under Window Logs / Security. I'm not exactly sure what info to be looking at. But the event ID is 4672 and 4624 and the task category is Special Logon and Logon

Comment: If this is LocalDB from SQL Server 2014 then they've changed the instance name. The connection string should use `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` in the case of SQL 2014.

Comment: hmm almost @KrzysztofKozielczyk. I tried what you said and got this error message... Cannot open database "ContosoUniversity1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'SEAN\Sean'.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance it is because you forgot to double-escape the backslash? Did you try this:

"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true"

Or even better, you could just use the @ mark to disable character escaping for the entire connection string:

@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true"

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i do in order to fix this problem

1. You need to install the sql server local db
2. Copy the local server of your local db in case you don't know here is how to find the local server name(You need to copy the highlighted part)

   [image: server name in sql server 2014]
3. Update the local server name in the connection string in the web.config file of the Contoso Project
   **Note that you only need to update the server name in you connection string do not replace the whole connection string with the server name.**
4. Re run all the migration one by one like this

   > update-database -TargetMigration MigratonName
5. Build the project and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Change application pool identity from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `LocalSystem` in IIS for your website application pool and `IntgretedSecurity = true` in config
will help you.

[image]